# Get table checksum in Laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel, checksum

What do you use to get the checksum of a table in Laravel? Is there something already abstracted for this or you have to use raw commands?

Comment: I doubt this is built into Eloquent/Fluent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use raw commands, but it is pretty easy, just add this method to your model:

```
public static function checksum()
{
    $tableName = with(new static)->getTable();
    $query = sprintf('CHECKSUM TABLE %s', $tableName);

    return \DB::select(\DB::raw($query))[0]->Checksum;
}
```

You can now call this method statically to get the checksum.